Nextflow fails to publish large files when there is an error downstream in the workflow
I am writing a nextflow workflow with two steps. First produces a couple of large files and second does a report fromt these. My problem is that when there is an error in the report sometimes it happens that not all of the large files are copied to the publishDir. Is there a way to force nextflow to stay alive until it completes publishing all files?

What mode are you using with publishDir? You could use link rather than the copy or move.
And how are you feeding these process 1 output files into the next process? To my knowledge, between processes in the workflow declaration, nextflow should symlink files between working directories.

Maybe you should look into the errorStrategy directive: here
